# SQL 'IN' and 'NOT IN' together

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an HABTM relation between 2 models Dish and Ingredient.
I would like to find al the dishes containing some ingredients but not containing others.

This is what I did:

```
likes = [1,2,3] # id of ingredients i like
dislikes = [6,7] # id of ingredients i don't like

@dishes = Dish.joins(:ingredients).where("ingredients.id IN (?) AND ingredients.id NOT IN (?)",likes,dislikes).group("dishes.id")
```

This is not returning the desired result and I can't find a way to do this with an SQL query. Any clue?

Comment: Looking at your query, I'm not seeing anything wrong..

Comment: You need to join twice. Each row includes a single ingredients.id.

Comment: What is the expected result. I would expect the ingredients list would be all ingredients in the dish and on the like list. Unless the likes and dislikes overlap.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround I found, don't know if there is a simpler way to do this.

```
right = Dish.joins(:ingredients).where("ingredients.id IN (#{likes})").group("dishes.id")
not_right = Dish.joins(:ingredients).where("ingredients.id IN (#{dislikes})").group("dishes.id")    
@dishes = right - not_right
```

Comment: It can be simplified into: `Dish.joins(:ingredients).where("ingredients.id IN (?)", likes - dislikes).group("dishes.id")`